# un intended output from the program on

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ on my own. I have come up with the following simple program:

```
  # include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()

{
    string name [50]={};
    char studentId [5]={};
    for (int x=0; x<3;x++)
    {
          cout<<"Enter the following details: "<<endl;
          cout<<" Name: ";
          cin>>name[x];
          cout<<"Student ID: ";
          cin>>studentId [x];
          cout<<"...................................................."<<endl;
    }

    for (int x=0; x<3;x++)
    {
          cout<<" Here are the details entered: "<<endl;
          cout<<" Name: "<<name<<endl;
          cout<<"Student ID: "<<studentId<<endl;
          cout<<"...................................................."<<endl;
    }

}
```

However when i compile it, it is not running the way i want it to be.
During the second and third iteration it prompts the user the following:
**Name: studentId...**
which is not what i want the program to do.
how can I edit it so that it runs perfectly?

Comment: My crystal ball says you're looking for `std::getline`.

Comment: You need to give us the inputs you are using, the output you get and the output you expect in order to make this answerable.

Comment: you declare `studentId` as an array of 5 char, so when your program reach the statement `cin>>studentId[x]` it actually reads only 1 char, while you probably entered a 5 digit ID, so the remaining chars are read by the next call to `cin>>`, without letting you enter anything. To "fix" it, just declare it as you did for name.